# Where is the resources.GetObject("") executing at?

Tags: c#, resources, custom-controls

I have a custom control on a form. Basically my Visual Studio has been fubared for the past 5 hours because my properties are loading at initialization.

**The code:**

```
this.customControl.customProp = ((System.Collections.Generic.List<customType>)(resources.GetObject("customControl.customProp")));
```

What I would like to know is where this code is actually being executed at or is it storing these pieces of data somewhere? What is killing me right now is that there is actually data associated with this resource object, however, the data doesn't get loaded until I query the database. I can't seem to find where its getting the data from.

I also, looked in the resource file and in the Other section and didn't see anything in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search your entire solution for "customControl.customProp" - that should show you where it's defined. It's going to be in a .resx file.

Comment: Ok I finally found it ty! The value is some long strings though. Does that mean that is my actual data but converted to something else?

Comment: It is a custom object that gets passed down via a WCF service. Or a list rather.

Comment: Depending on the type, what you see in the .resx may be an actual value or a text representation of binary data. It sounds like you're seeing the latter.

Comment: Ok so somehow my property is being cached. I wonder how that happened.

Comment: How can I configure the default value for that? Designer is choosing an invalid value for my control property.

Comment: I believe that is encoded by the control vendor (by setting the value in the constructor, usually).