# How do I stop my controls from generating resource files for my data lists?

Tags: c#, properties, resources, custom-controls

So I have built quite a few custom controls and I have been having problems with controls that have types of System.Collections.Generics.Lists<>() in them. Basically they are caching their results into a resource file and saving my main form's designer code to reference the resource file instead just being a normal list.

The List<> is getting populated from a WCF data source way after runtime.

This is becoming a problem because I have code that fills a listview on the set methods of those properties. So how can I tell my control not to cache the results of my properties. I assume I would have to first telling it to cache results but I am not.

My properties look like this in the control.

```
private List<Job> _jobs;


public List<Job> Jobs {
    get { return _jobs; }
    set { _jobs = value; }
}
```

Then they are getting set like this in my Main's forms designer code.

```
this.customControl.Jobs = ((System.Collections.Generic.List<Jobs>)(resources.GetObject("customControl.Jobs")));
```

I have asked a pre-cursor to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639632/where-is-the-resources-getobject-executing-at)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add this attribute on your property :

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public List<Job> Jobs {
   get { return _jobs; }
   set { _jobs = value; }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense to mee too, especially after reading through the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.

Comment: Thank you and sorry its taken me so long to get back to you on this. My main problem was that I had code setting the property in the controls load event. So it was running that code and caching the results. This allowed me to not cache but leave the code where it was. Perfect!